# How to find the weight function, with respect to which a family of polynomials is orthogonal?

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

When iteratively findind the best polynomial approximation wrt. $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{\infty}$, a good starting point for the process is the projection onto the basis of Chebyshev 1st kind polynomials, because their monic multiple have minimal $L_{\infty}$ norm. Similarly a Legendre projection is used for an $L_2$ approximation.

However, I think it maybe is better to use the projection onto the family of polynomials that has minimal $L_p$ norm for the multiple with $P_n(1)=1$ rather than the monic multiple. For $p=\infty$ it makes no difference, but for $p=2$ it does.

For $p=2$, the family has this 3-term recurrence relation:

$$P_0(x) = 1\quad,\quad P_1(x) = x\quad,\quad
P_{n+1}(x) = \frac{3 + 2n}{3 + n}xP_{n}(x) - \frac{n}{3 + n} P_{n-1}(x)$$

The roots of $P_n(x)$ are the eigenvalues of $M_n$, where
$$M_n=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & b(1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 b(1) & 0 & b(2) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & b(2) & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & b(n-1) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b(n-1) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\quad,\quad b(n)=\sqrt{n/(3/(n+2)+4n)}$$
Is this a named/wellknown family? If no, how is the weight function related to the recurrence relation and $M_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p = 2$ the recurrence relation has Gegenbauer polynomials as solutions. First normalize the recurrence relation to
$$
x p_n(x) = p_{n+1}(x) + \frac{n(n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)} p_{n-1}(x).
$$
Compare with the normalized recurrence relation for the [Jacobi polynomials](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/askey/ch1/par8/par8.html), so that
$$
p_n(x) = \frac{2^n n!}{(n+3)_n}P^{(1,1)}_n(x).
$$
The Jacobi polynomials for which $\alpha = \beta$ can be written as Gegenbauer polynomials. Therefore with $\lambda = \frac{3}{2}$,
$$
P^{(1,1)}_n(x) = \frac{(2)_n}{(3)_n} C_n^{(\frac{3}{2})}(x) = \frac{2}{n+2} C^{(\frac{3}{2})}_n(x).
$$
The weight function for these [Gegenbauer polynomials](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/askey/ch1/par8/par8.html#par1) is $w(x) = 1 - x^2$.

Best,
Noud